# Bank transfer to a friend?

Tags: money-transfer

Can I transfer from my Wells Fargo account to another person's Wells Fargo account?

Comment: @BobBaerker note that Zelle and Cashapp didn't exist back then.

Comment: By Wells Fargo do you mean Wells Fargo bank accounts, or do you mean Wells Fargo investment accounts?

Comment: Have you asked Wells Fargo?

Answer (score 3):

WF supports Zelle, which allows instantaneous transfer to other accounts of up to $2,000 per day.  I use it to regularly transfer money to my father (borrowed money from him) who's at the same bank I am, and son.

And, of course, you can write your friend a check, use PayPal, Cashapp, etc.